# Is there a way to validate JSPs automatically upon save in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, jsp

Does anybody know if there's a setting that will ensure a JSP file will automatically get validated when you save changes to it? I know you can use `right-click -> validate` to manually validate the file but it would be easier to be able to have it done automatically.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Properties --> Validation for 'build' happens automatically when a build happens. Look under `Project` and see if the `Build Automatically` is set. If Eclipse is set this way, a build should happen when you save the file, and so will `validation`.

[image: Validation Setting in Eclipse]

Comment: That is already set by default unfortunately :( validation of JSPs never seems to occur upon a build, whether it be manual or automatic. Only when I right click on a file and select the  'validate' option manually.